# How to capitalize middle row of a column in PySpark or Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I have a CSV file three columns values

```
    1st Column   2nd Column   3rd Column
    ram          karthi       bruce
    RAM          KATHI        BRUCE
    ram          karthi       bruce
```

I want to capitalize the 2nd row like ram,karthi and bruce in Pyspark or Pandas...
I am not able to do. Please help. Solution in PySpark will be more helpful..

Comment: Spark does not have a concept of index, so '2nd row' is not a well-defined row. It's not something that is meaningful in spark.

Comment: I guess it can be done..

Comment: No it cannot. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36938976/why-spark-sql-considers-the-support-of-indexes-unimportant

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43406887/spark-dataframe-how-to-add-a-index-column-aka-distributed-data-index

Comment: The code with zipWithIndex does not work for me in Pyspark ..Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

In Pandas, you can do it using [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and  [`Series.str.upper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.upper.html):

```
In [1619]: df
Out[1619]: 
  1st_Column 2nd_Column 3rd_Column
0        ram     karthi      bruce
1        ram     karthi      bruce
2        ram     karthi      bruce

In [1620]: df.loc[1] = df.loc[1].str.upper()

In [1621]: df
Out[1621]: 
  1st_Column 2nd_Column 3rd_Column
0        ram     karthi      bruce
1        RAM     KARTHI      BRUCE
2        ram     karthi      bruce
```

Comment: I am not too sure how to do this in `PySpark`.